# Javascript library for managing viewport layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, extjs, extjs4

In the past I have used a lot of ExtJS to make dashboards. One of my favorite features is the  full-screen viewport with `border layout` which helps you to split up a dashboard into panels on the left, right, top and bottom, without creating scrollbars everywhere. see e.g. these [examples](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html).

Is there a JS library or jQuery plugin that does just this? I am making a dashboard and want to split the screen into panels, but ExtJS is a bit bloated and overkill only to use for the boarder layout.

Comment: I left JQuery due to ExtJS being much, much better. Why go back?

Comment: I don't want to be tied to the Ext widgets. jQuery is more basic, you can use other widgets and libraries. I'm using it together with bootstrap, D3, leaflet, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ext JS is a great solution for this but if you are looking for something else then the jQuery UI Layout Plugin may be the option you want.

Example:
http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/simple.html

Project Home Page:
http://layout.jquery-dev.net/

Answer (score 0):

[Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) provides help for the layout but you have to follow a certain design and am not sure it manages fullscreen apps with no scroll.

I think it's worth a look though.

You may look at [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/) which now integrates well with jquery and has nice widgets (tabs placed on the left for example, grids) and a good layout system.